# How to start an activity when an accessibility service is connected?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-service, accessibilityservice

I have two activities `MainActivity.java`, `MainActivity2.java` and an accessibility service `MyService.java`. From `MainActivity.java`, I start the Accessibility Settings Activity using the following code:

```
Intent intentStartSettingActivity = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_SETTINGS);
startActivity(intentStartSettingActivity);
```

From the settings activity, the user can turn on the accessibility service for the application. Now, when the user enables the accessibility permission, I want to start a new activity `MainActivity2.java` but the problem is when I am enabling the accessibility permission, the activity `MainActivity2.java` is not displayed. For starting second activity I am using the following code in `MyService.java`:

```
@Override
    protected void onServiceConnected() {
        super.onServiceConnected();
        Intent intentStartMainActivity2 = new Intent(this,MainActivity2.class);
        intentStartMainActivity2.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intentStartMainActivity2);
    }
```

When I am viewing the Logcat its showing as:

```
2019-12-26 21:53:41.249 23580-23580/com.example.tatkal I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request time:68381132 intent:Intent { flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.example.tatkal/.MainActivity2 }
```

This means that the service is connecting properly but I don't know why the activity is not being displayed.